# Logical ports for Windows 7, 8, 10

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, windows-8

I have different computers that I am trying to investigate right now. Each computer has a PID 4 with different ports. Now, what I am trying to figure out is what process could be running on these ports? Some of the ports are saying `Cannot obtain ownership information`. We have tried using different software such as Process Explorer, Currports and TCPview. Based on our research there are `system`related processes. Is there a way to learn more what these system related processes are?

On this computer, we have processes on PID 4 that runs on Ports 4343, 8080, 8530, 8531 and 49152-65535. We want to know what processes/services are running on these ports but all the tools that we used so far only says Cannot obtain ownership information. Is there a tool or way to find out more about these services/processes?

Thanks,
mrabena

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi Ramhound, Thank you for the reply. To clarify, I will use one of the computers that we are working on. On this computer, we have processes on PID 4 that runs on Ports 4343, 8080, 8530, 8531 and 49152-65535. We want to know what processes/services are running on these ports but all the tools that we used so far only says Cannot obtain ownership information. Is there a tool or way to find out more about these services/processes/

Comment: You need to clarify your question by editing it

Answer (score 2):

If you keep getting "Can't get ownership information" you are NOT running the tools with Administrator rights. You'll need admin-rights in order to get that sort of information.

But from the numbers of those TCP ports I can tell that they are almost 100% guaranteed to belong to Internet Information Server. 
8530 and 8531 are the default ports for WSUS which is an application running on IIS and 4343 and 8080 are commonly used alternatives for https and http in case the default ports (443 and 80) are not available.

Run "netstat -b" from an CMD prompt (started with "Run as Administrator") and it should tell you which EXE file is associated with each port.

Comment: We found out that we are running the tools with Admin rights and still get the "Cannot obtain ownership information". We have been running "Netstat-abno" from the CMD prompt (run as an admin) but some of the ports are still not showing the processes.

Comment: @mrabena If that is the case I suspect your system administrator has provided additional security policies (most likely through Group Policy) on those computers. Check with your IT department. If they don't want to relax those restrictions, they should at least be able to provide you with the information you need about those ports.